# Amazon EC2 instances network issues

Tags: amazon-ec2

We had few instances of our system on EC2. Some of them application servers, some of them Memcached, Database and etc. 
After few weeks after creating instance, it starts to raise a lot number of errors depending to network: errors like "MEMCACHED TIMEOUT ERROR", "RABBITMQ connection error" and same. Errors happens only from single instance. After creating copy of this instance - errors goes away. 
Did anybody have same problems?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this before. I think it has to do with problems with the network stack of the host, at least that is as much information I could get form aws.

If you are using EBS backed instances. Simply stopping and then restarting the instance should solve the problem. The instance gets assigned to a new host in that case.